# jtidy isn't parsing well a freemarker html code

Tags: java, html, css, freemarker, jtidy

The method:

```
public static String convertHtmlEntities(String htmlString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String result = null;

        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");
        tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(false); // only print the content
        tidy.setXmlOut(true); // to XML
        tidy.setSmartIndent(true); 
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
        result =  outputStream.toString("UTF-8");

        return result;
    }
```

What enters through htmlString as a parameter:

```
"<#macro print_bono voucher>
<div id="content">
            <div class="icn_fold2"><div class="text"></div></div>
            <div id="area1">
                <div id="bg1">
                    <p class="barcode"><img src="${voucher.barcode}" alt="${voucher.numberCode}" /></p>
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1>&#201;sta es tu entrada</h1>
                        <p class="note"><strong>IMPORTANTE:</strong> Para acceder al recinto hay que presentar esta hoja entera</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="services_bg">
                        <p class="logo_fcb"><img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/logos_fcb.gif" alt="FCB, LFP" /></p>
                        <div class="service">
                            <table width="260">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="85"><strong>Jornada:</strong></td>
                                    <td width="45">${voucher.jornada}</td>
                                    <td width="85"><strong>Temporada:</strong></td>
                                    <td width="45">${temporada}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="85" colspan="2"><strong>Fecha*:</strong></td>
                                    <td colspan="2">${voucher.serviceDate}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="85" colspan="2"><strong>Partido:</strong></td>
                                    <td colspan="2">${voucher.match}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4"><strong>*</strong> <i>Se recomienda verificar la fecha y hora del partido en <span>www.fcbarcelona.cat</span></i></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="130" colspan="2"><strong>Zona:</strong></td>
                                    <td colspan="2">${voucher.zoneDescription}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="130" colspan="2"><strong>Acceso recomendado:</strong></td>
                                    <td colspan="2">${voucher.access}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="85"><strong>Puerta:</strong></td>
                                    <td>${voucher.entranceDoor}</td>
                                    <td width="85"><strong>Boca:</strong></td>
                                    <td>${voucher.gate}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="85"><strong>Fila:</strong></td>
                                    <td>${voucher.row}</td>
                                    <td width="85"><strong>Asiento:</strong></td>
                                    <td>${voucher.seat}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4"> </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="price">
                                    <td width="130" colspan="2"><strong>Precio:</strong></td>
                                    <td colspan="2"><span>10.080 EUR  &#8364;</span></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="logo_hex">
                        <p>CIF:G08266298</p>
                        <img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/logo_hotelextras.gif" alt="hotelextras" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="area2">
                <div id="bg2">
                    <h1>C&#243;mo llegar</h1>
                    <p class="map"><img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/img_mapa.gif" alt="" /></p>
                    <p class="logos_pie"><img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/logos_pie.gif" alt="" /></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icn_fold1"><div class="text"></div></div>
            <div id="area3">
                <div id="bg3">
                    <div id="banner-content">
                        <div class="banner">
                            <img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/banner.jpg" alt="" />                         
                            <img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/logo_sensefum.gif" alt="" style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px;"/>
                            <span class="publi">publicitat</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="area4">
                <div id="bg4">
                    <p class="note"><strong>IMPORTANTE:</strong> Para acceder al recinto hay que presentar esta hoja entera</p>
                    <div class="info">
                        <ul class="instructions">
                            <li><strong>Prohibida la reproducci&#243;n total o parcial de este documento.</strong><br />El FCBarcelona se reserva el derecho de denegar el acceso al recinto en caso de que se detecte la posible duplicaci&#243;n de esta entrada. El titular de la compra se responsabiliza del buen uso de esta entrada.</li>
                            <li><strong class="txt_rose">Para validar la entrada en el mecanismo de control, hay que doblarla como indicamos:</strong><img src="http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/img_pliegue.gif" alt="" /></li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="attention"><strong>ATENCI&#211;N:</strong> Si alguien te ofrece venderte esta entrada no la aceptes. No tendr&#237;a ning&#250;n valor oficial y, por lo tanto, ser&#237;a una copia no autorizada.</p>
                        <h2>Instrucciones y condiciones importantes</h2>
                        <p>La tenencia y/o uso de esta entrada significa la aceptaci&#243;n expresa de todos los t&#233;rminos y condiciones asociados a la entrada y ratificados durante el proceso de compra. En caso de duda, consulta de nuevo las condiciones en <strong>www.fcbarcelona.cat</strong></p>
                        <ul class="list1">
                            <li><strong>El c&#243;digo de barras de esta entrada permite el acceso al recinto s&#243;lo una vez.</strong> Cualquier duplicado de la misma, bajo ning&#250;n concepto, podr&#225; dar acceso al recinto.</li>
                            <li>En caso de que aparezcan copias duplicadas, el FCBarcelona adoptar� las medidas oportunas, <strong>denegando el acceso al recinto.</strong></li>
                            <li>
                                Reglamento para la prevenci&#243;n de la violencia en espect&#225;culos deportivos. <strong>Causas que impiden el acceso al recinto:</strong>
                                <ul class="list2">
                                    <li>La introducci&#243;n de bebidas alcoh&#243;licas, armas e instrumentos susceptibles de ser utilizados como tales, bengalas, fuegos de artificio u objetos an&#225;logos.</li>
                                    <li>La introducci&#243;n y exhibici&#243;n de pancartas, s&#237;mbolos, emblemas o leyendas que impliquen incitaci&#243;n a la violencia.</li>
                                    <li>Que el portador haya sido sancionado con la prohibici&#243;n de acceso a cualquier recinto deportivo, mientras no se haya extinguido la sanci&#243;n.</li>
                                    <li>Encontrarse bajo los efectos de bebidas alcoh&#243;licas, estupefacientes, psicotr&#243;picos, estimulantes o sustancias an&#225;logas.</li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="icn_fold1 icn_fold1_right"><div class="text"></div></div>
            <div class="icn_fold2 icn_fold2_bottom"><div class="text"></div></div>          
    </div>
</#macro>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Voucher</title>
        <style>
            body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, fieldset, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
            fieldset, img {
                border: 0 none;
            }
            address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {
                font-style: normal;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            ol, ul, li {
                list-style: none outside none;
            }
            caption, th {
                text-align: left;
            }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
                font-size: 100%;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
            body {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                color: #000000;
                font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                font-size: 10px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                text-align: left;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 15px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
                text-align: center;
                color:#fff;
            }
            #content {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            #content #bg1 .title h1 {
                color:#fff;
                padding:0;
                margin-top:6px;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #content #bg1 .title {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/bg_title.png") repeat-y left top;
                width: 309px;
                height: 44px;
                margin: 0 0 0 6px;
            }
            .note {
                color:#fff;
                padding:0;
                font-size: 8px;
                margin-bottom: 8px;
            }
            .note strong {
                font-size: 9px;
            }
            .txt_rose {
                color:#A30245;
            }
            #content #bg4 .note {
                padding: 0;
                text-align:center;
            }
            #content #bg1 .services_bg {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/bg_services.png") no-repeat left top;
                width:309px;
                height: 238px;
                margin: 0 0 0 6px;
            }
            #content #bg1 .logo_fcb {
                margin-top:4px;
            }
            #content #bg1 .price span {
                font-size: 15px;
                color:#000;
            }
            a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
            .first {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
            .last {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
            .clear {
                clear: both;
                display: block;
                height: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                visibility: hidden;
                width: 0;
            }
            .left {
                float:left;
            }
            .right {
                float:right;
            }
            .icn_fold1 {
                position:absolute;
                top:500px;
                left:7px;
                font-size:8px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color:#A30245;
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/icn_fold1_cas.gif") no-repeat left top;
                height:217px;
                z-index: 100;
                *width:40px;
            }
            .icn_fold2 {
                position:absolute;
                top:6px;
                left:245px;
                font-size:8px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color:#A30245;
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/icn_fold2_cas.gif") no-repeat left top;
                height:26px;
                z-index: 100;
            }
            .icn_fold1_right {
                left:680px;
            }
            .icn_fold2_bottom {
                top:965px;
            }
            .icn_fold1 .text {
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
                margin-left: -145px;
                margin-top: -72px;
                *margin-left: 3px;
                *margin-top: -115px;
                margin-left: 3px\0/;
                margin-top: -115px\0/;
                width: 300px;
            }
            .icn_fold2 .text {
                margin-left: 15px;
                margin-top: -2px;
                width: 300px;
            }
            strong {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            #content {
                width:720px;
            }
            #content div {
                float:left;
            }
            #content #area1 {
                width: 350px;
                border-right: 1px dashed #A30245;
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #A30245;
            }
            #content #area2 {
                width: 354px;
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #A30245;
            }
            #content #area3 {
                width: 350px;
                border-right: 1px dashed #A30245;
            }
            #content #area4 {
                width: 354px;
            }
            #content #bg1 {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/bg1.png") no-repeat left top;
                width: 321px;
                height: 457px;
                margin: 25px 8px 8px 25px;
            }
            #content #bg1 p {
                text-align: center;
            }
            #content #bg2 {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/bg2.png") no-repeat left top;
                width: 321px;
                height: 457px;
                margin: 25px 25px 8px 4px;
            }
            #content #bg3 {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/bg3.png") no-repeat left top;
                width: 321px;
                height: 457px;
                margin: 8px 8px 25px 25px;
                text-align:center;
                display: table;
                position: relative;
            }
            #content #bg4 {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/bg4.png") no-repeat left top;
                width: 321px;
                height: 457px;
                margin: 8px 0px 25px 4px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .info {
                padding: 5px 0px 0px 13px;
                font-size:8px;
            }
            #content #bg4 ul {
                float:left;
            }
            #content #bg4 .instructions li{
                width:148px;
                display: inline;
                float:left;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .instructions img{
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .attention {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/ico_par.gif") no-repeat left top;
                padding: 0px 15px 4px 10px;
                margin: 3px 0 3px 0;
                float:left;
                /**width:580px;*/
            }
            #content #bg4 .attention strong {
                font-size: 9px;
            }
            #content #bg4 h2 {
                font-size: 10px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                float:left;
                color:#A30245;
                font-weight: bold;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                /**width:620px;*/
            }
            #content #bg4 p {
                float:left;
                padding-right: left;
            }
            #content #bg4 p.note {
                float:none;
                margin-top:13px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .list1 {
                margin:5px 0 0 0px;
                font-size: 8px;
                padding-right: 10px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .list1 li {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/ico_line1.png") no-repeat 0 2px;
                padding-left:8px;
                margin-bottom:5px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .list2 {
                margin-top: 10px;
                *margin-left:20px;
            }
            #content #bg4 .list2 li {
                background: url("http://evo.cdnstc.com/static/images/bono_ds/ico_line2.png") no-repeat left 3px;
            }
            #content .service {
                margin: 10px 10px 5px 18px;
                width: 268px;
            }
            #content .service table {
                margin-bottom:15px;
                font-size:9px;
            }
            #content .service table strong {
                color: #A30245;
            }
            #content .service table span {
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #content .service table tr.lastd td {
                border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
                padding-bottom:20px;
            }
            #content .access strong{
                font-size: 10px;
                color: #FF0000;
            }
            #content #bg1 .logo_hex {
                margin: -20px 0 0 6px;
                width: 309px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #content #bg1 .logo_hex img {
                margin-top: 45px;
            }
            #content #bg2 .map {
                margin:0 0 0 7px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #content #bg2 .logos_pie {
                text-align:center;
                margin-top: 27px;
            }
            #content #bg3 .banner {
                position:relative;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                *position: absolute;
                *bottom: 0px;
                *left:0px;
            }
            #content #bg3 #banner-content {
                margin-top: 100px;
                float:none;
            }
            #content #bg3 #banner-content .publi {
                float:right;
                font-size:8px;
                margin:3px 14px 0 0;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            #content .locator {
                text-align: center;
                float: none;
                font-size:10px;
            }
            #content .barcode {
                margin: 9px 0 5px 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <#list vouchers as voucher>
            <@print_bono voucher />

            <#if voucher_has_next>
                <br /><br /><br /><br />
            </#if>
        </#list>  
    </body>
</html>"
```

What fills in result just before the return sentence:

```
"<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 2009-12-01), see jtidy.sourceforge.net" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
"
```

I can't even imagine what's going wrong... Any help or guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't even think that's possible. A freemarker template is not valid (x)html which jtidy is meant for. The only thing I can think of is that you first process the freemarker template and do the jtidy afterwards.